# PHP string not outputting html tags?

Tags: php, html, string

I have an array of strings that contain html `<object>`'s like so:

```
$str = '<object width="600" height="338">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>';
```

Going through a loop of them, each inside a , I am echoing them out.

The problem is that instead of echoing the DOM elements, the string is being printed like so:

```
<div>
"<object width="600" height="338">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed"></param>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
    </object>"
</div>
```

The quotation marks are used as if I am printing an array, but I have checked that the type of the var is string.

What is going on here?

**EDIT:**

My string is actually pulled from an API, where I parse some info and use the follow array:

```
Array
(
    [content] => <object width="600" height="338"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
    [width] => 600
    [scrolling] => 
    [height] => 338
)
```

I pick up `[content]` and am trying to output the `<object>` itself.

Comment: Your sample isn't valid - You'd either need to use single quotes for the string or escape all of the double quotes in the string.

Comment: Your string variable is being output through `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()`.

Comment: The sample code doesn't parse, because you wrap it in double quotes and the string includes un-escaped double quotes. Please include your actual code, as this is related to your problem. At a guess, I'd say your actual string is declared like `$str = '"<!-- content -->"'`, and you need to remove the surrounding double quotes.

Comment: My string wasn't actually declared like that - please see the edit.

Comment: @samb so rather than confusing everyone who has provided an answer why dont you put the actual code your using

Comment: It was virtually the same effect until i realised the quotes were wrong. It was wrong for about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `html_entity_decode` on the string fixed this.

Comment: why downvote? the string didn't have quote/escape issues, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your use of double quotes :

Try (the string is enclosed with single quotes)

```
$str = '<object width="600" height="338">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="600" height="338" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
</object>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your strings.

```
$str = "<object width=\"600\" height=\"338\">
<param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed\"></param>
<param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param>
<param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"></param>
<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/YQSFQUkVUos?version=3&feature=oembed\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></embed>
</object>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a due to you declaring a string with " and that string contains " marks. Try convert the html to have single quotes ' or declare the string with singles quotes or even escape the double quotes in the HTML with a backslash \"